# Rails assets not loaded on Nginx + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, nginx, asset-pipeline, passenger

I'm trying to setup Rails 4 on Passenger + Nginx. I deployed my app to Aws ubuntu.
The app is loaded when I visit the public IP but there is no CSS or image on the page.

Here are what I did:

- In nginx site-enables config:

> ```
> server {
>   listen 80 default_server;
>   server_name my_ip_here;
>   passenger_enabled on;
>   rails_env production;
>   root /path_to_public;
> }
> ```

Application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "select2.min.css";
@import "toastr.css";
@import "magnific-popup.css";
@import "jgallery.css";
@import "rateit.css";
@import "load-awesome.css";
@import "dropzone.css";
@import "auto-complete.css";
@import "main.css";
@import "green.css";
@import "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css";
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_files = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

After that I tried to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production but no CSS and image still.

I read several posts on this website and attempted to add this line into assets.rb but it will give me error undefined variable: "$alert-padding" when precompiling the assets

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '**/*.js', '*.scss']
```

I found this in the log but not sure if it's related:

```
# current user is: ubuntu
# mkdir -p /usr/lib/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
Encountered permission error, trying a different directory...
-------------------------------
# mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.passenger/native_support/5.0.26/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
# cd /home/ubuntu/.passenger/native_support/5.0.26/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
# /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby /usr/lib/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/lib/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb (LoadError)
```

***UPDATE 1:***

I updated my nginx config file per Rails documentation

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name my_public_ip;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /home/..../public;
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message in your browser console for the files that failed to load?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for all of the files imported in application.css.scss

Comment: Are you sure the browser is looking for the files on the same IP you're using to access the app?